# Are there any other entities, apart from Flanders, whose parliament and government are located outside its territory?

Tags: parliament

The [Flanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanders) [parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flemish_Parliament) and [government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flemish_Government) are located outside Flanders in the [Brussels capital region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brussels).

That should be rather unusual, as it has no say there.

Is there any other subnational entity where parliament and government are officially located outside the area over which it has influence?

(Governments in exile come to mind but this is an entirely different situation)

Comment: The Flemish Government is the executive branch of *both* Flemish Community and Flemish Region. The same is true for the Flemish Parliament. Brussels is part of the Flemish Community, but not the Flemish Region! So the Flemish Government as a whole is located inside its area of influence. It only has partly influence over the area it's located in.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Aha.  I thought that the Flemish Community and the Flemish Region each had their own parliament and government, assuming the Flemish Community is the same as the Flemish/Dutch Language Community.

Comment: Your assumption is correct (Flemish Community is the language-based community, but has competences beyond the language, that's another topic), but your thought is not (there's only one government and one parliament for both the Community and Region).

Comment: Quite a few German districts have their administrative seat in a city that itself does not belong to the district; e.g. _Landkreis Osnabrück_ (seat in Osnabrück), _Rhein-Neckar-Kreis_ (seat in Heidelberg).

Answer (score 7):

- Until recently, Moscow oblast government was located in Moscow, which is not part of Moscow oblast. Now it has been moved to Krasnogorsk, which belongs to Moscow oblast.
- Leningrad oblast government is located in St. Petersburg, which is not part of Leningrad oblast.
- Antarctica's administration is located in Buenos Aires.

Comment: Your third bullet point needs clarification.  Do you mean the administration of [the part of Antarctica claimed by Argentina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentine_Antarctica), a claim not internationally recognised?

Comment: @gerrit no, I mean the office of Antarctic Treaty Secretariat, and the incumbent Executive Secretary http://www.ats.aq/index_e.htm are located there. They administer Antarctica. The legislative body meetings (ATCM) are conducted in various countries (the upcoming will be in China, the last one was in Chile).

Comment: I see.  I'm not sure if I would call that a *government* and it is a territory with no inhabitants, but it does remind me that probably some tiny colonies are (still) remotely administrated.

Comment: @gerrit definitely! There are even uninhabited territories and islands.

Comment: Kievan oblast and Minsk oblast share the same pattern with Moscow and Leningrad (city is not subordinated to region, but regional government and legislature is located here nevertheless).  Generally speking, that seems to be pretty common at least in former Soviet Republics.

Answer (score 5):

In Virginia, cities are legally distinct from counties, unlike in most US states where the city is a political subdivision of the county. Some county seats are in cities. An example is that of Rockbridge county, which is located in the city of Lexington, outside of (but entirely surrounded by) Rockbridge county.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, due to boundary changes in 1965, Surrey County Council has its headquarters in the neighbouring local government area, the Royal Borough of Kingston upon Thames.